# My computer doesn't power off when I shut down if it has been running for a long time

Tags: power-management, shutdown

I did some research on similar posts but so far I couldn't find the exact problem that I have.

If I turn on the computer and then I shut it down right after starting the session it works, but if the system has been running for a while and then I shut down, sometimes (not always) it gets frozen after pressing the shut down button. I've tried to reinstall Ubuntu keeping my encrypted home directory but the problems remains. I have a HP ProBook 4330s and Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. Battery is quite worn-out but I don't know if that may affect it. I am still a Linux beginner... Where can I find more info in order to keep looking for a solution?

Comment: Try hitting the `ESC` during shutdown, and you should see a textual screen that may be able to tell you where/why it doesn't shutdown correctly. You may have an app or service that is not gracefully shutting down.

Comment: thanks @heynnema. I'll try it but the problem is that not always crash and once it happen the screen gets frozen and I am not sure if ESC would work. Anyway, we will see.

Comment: I've tried and as I said `ESC` didn't work while shutting down but thanks anyway. Any other suggestion to find out what's causing the problem?

Comment: The `ESC` only works after you've selected shutdown from the menu. You're going to have to look at the system log files around the time of the freeze/crash. In `terminal`, type `more /var/log/syslog*`, and find out what was going on just before, and up to, the freeze/crash.

Comment: I've checked it sometimes but there are many process and I am not sure how to interpret and pull apart the problematic lines.

Comment: I've tried different possible solutions found around and the problem is still no fixed... Any guidelines please? I don't know what else try.

Comment: Please any guideline? I don't know what else to do and I am worried for my laptop having to force power off all the times it gets frozen...

Comment: I have formatted the whole computer and I have reinstalled ubuntu but after a day working correctly and after having copied some files (documents, pictures, videos etc.) of my old home from a hard disk drive, again, I have problems to turn it off. It stays frozen while shutting down and no command is working. I would really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

After some time I finally managed to fix the problem. Actually I solved it by accident, I had a problem with RAM and when I changed it to a new one the problem of turning off the computer has disappeared so I deduce that this was the problem. Thank you all.